# How to change color of a Tkinter treeview's row based on condition with python?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I'm trying to change row colors of my program. I've already seen many tutorials and visited so many more websites but none of what the say works. This is my code, I don't understand where is the problem. The program runs without errors by the way. Thank you guys in advanced!

```
def base_datos(self):
    self.tabla = ttk.Treeview(self, column=('Nombre', 'Apellidos', 'Correo', 'Número', 'Estado'),
                              selectmode='browse')

    scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.tabla.yview)
    scroll.place(relx=0.968, rely=0.304, height=326)
    self.tabla.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

    self.tabla.column('#0', anchor='c')
    self.tabla.column('#1', anchor='c')
    self.tabla.column('#2', anchor='c')
    self.tabla.column('#3', anchor='c')
    self.tabla.column('#4', anchor='c')
    self.tabla.column('#5', anchor='c')

    self.tabla.heading('#0', text='ID')
    self.tabla.heading('#1', text='Nombre')
    self.tabla.heading('#2', text='Apellidos')
    self.tabla.heading('#3', text='Correo')
    self.tabla.heading('#4', text='Número')
    self.tabla.heading('#5', text='Estado')

    self.tabla.tag_configure('sub', background='#6FE87F')
    self.tabla.tag_configure('no-sub', background='#D45E5E')

    self.lista_usuarios = Usuario.mostrar_db()
    self.lista_usuarios.reverse()

    for u in self.lista_usuarios:
        if self.sub_caducada(u[5]):
            my_tag = 'no-sub'
        else:
            my_tag = 'sub'
        self.tabla.insert('', 'end', text=u[0], values=(u[1], u[2], u[3], u[4], u[5]), tags=(my_tag,))

    self.tabla.place(relx=0.02, rely=0.3, width=1345, height=330)
```

Comment: What Python version / bitness (32 or 64 bit) are you using? I've seen some odd behavior where tag styles don't get applied to `Treeview` widgets sometimes.

Comment: I'm using python 3.8.8 in windows x64bits

Comment: Try updating your Python to >= 3.10